# Extraer y validar Información de dataframes python

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles, python-3.7

Buen día.

Tengo una tabla en CVS en la cual requiero filtrar la siguiente información:

```
----------
CLIENTE     ID_CLIENTE   NUMERO_SERVICIOS
CLIENTE A     3356           1
CLIENTE B     6656           6
CLIENTE C     6809           2
CLIENTE A     3356           3
```

Mi problema es el reconocimiento del cliente; debe reconocer cuando el id_cliente se repite y si es así debe sumar los servicios del cliente repetido.

### Ejemplo

```
CLIENTE     ID_CLIENTE   NUMERO_SERVICIOS
**CLIENTE A     3356           4**
CLIENTE B     6656           6
CLIENTE C     6809           2
```

Por ahora se esta filtrando con Dataframes
Les adjunto el código

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
file_FW_powbi = pd.read_excel('clientes.xlsx')
columnas = file_FW_powbi[(file_FW_powbi['Estatus OT'] == 'ACTIVO') & (file_FW_powbi['Estatus Servicio'] == 'ACTIVO')]
list_ClientActive = columnas.loc[:, ['Nombre Comercial','Sum of Cantidad','Id Cliente']]
dfs = {ID:group for ID, group in list_ClientActive.groupby('Id Cliente')}
```

Sin embargo, falta manipular los clientes para sumar el número de servicios de cada ID filtrado

Comment: Bienvenido kale a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que hayas intentando hasta ahora y que problema has tenido.  Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a usar un  `groupby()` esta operación sirve exactamente para eso.

Tu código sería algo así:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
file_FW_powbi = pd.read_excel('clientes.xlsx')

#Hacemos Groupby
file_FW_powbi.groupby(['id_cliente']).sum()
```

El `groupby` lo que hace es agrupar los valores iguales de la/s columna/s seleccionada/s y se le aplica la **operación de agregación** que elijamos, en este caso la que necesitas que es `.sum()`

Considero que este es **uno de los operadores más importantes que tiene Pandas**, ya que ahorra una gran cantidad de trabajo. Por ello te recomiendo que leas su documentación [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) y además práctiques ejercicios para aprender a usarlo.

Su funcionamiento es similar (aunque no exactamente igual) al de SQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo, me ayudo mucho a concluir el código.

Comment: De nada @kale ! Como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta" y porque no, puntuar positivamente la respuesta, si te ha parecido buena!